# Which versions of NLog work with VS2010 RTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nlog

Taking a look at [NLog](http://nlog.codeplex.com/), it's unclear what version works with VS2010. It says that NLog 1.0 Refresh works with VS2010 beta but nothing else is indicated. There's an NLog 2.0 that is pre-beta that I'd rather not use if I didn't have to but it clearly does work with VS2010.

So I'm wondering if I'm able to use 1.0 Refresh or do I need to go with 2.0 Preview 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both NLog 1.0 and 2.0 work with Visual Studio 2010. In case of 1.0 you need to use a build for .NET 2.0 (which unfortunately requires your app to be compiled against .NET Framework 4 Extended Profile), NLog 2.0 does not have this limitation and allows client profile apps as well.

For new projects I would recommend NLog 2.0. It is reasonably stable at this point and is passing all unit tests at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to use NLog 2.0. i had problems with 1.0 on vs 2010. i've tested 2.0 on Windows Application and it Works.